# Drupal 8 Webform - Loop the Result in Remote Post

Tags: 8, webforms

I am a PHP and Drupal 8 newbie.  I am working on a module based on Drupal 8 Webform and remote post.

I'd like to loop the request sent rather than doing a request->get('keyname') on each.  I'm hoping to using the parameter name to search another string and then replace it with the parameter's value in that string.

Any small foreach example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$request` is a Symfony request object:

```
foreach ($request->request->all() as $key => $value) {
  // ...
}
```